# Flutter 2: Reload not performed Analysis issues found (no issoues)

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, build

I am working on a flutter project and sometimes the reload does not works whereas I have no issues. I have everything up to date, every path right set, etc. I am on a stable version of android studio.

[image]

Does somebody have any idea ?

Here my flutter doctor:

```
C:\lib\flutter\bin\flutter.bat doctor --verbose
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.5.0, on Microsoft Windows [version 10.0.19042.1165], locale fr-FR)
    • Flutter version 2.5.0 at C:\lib\flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 4cc385b4b8 (3 days ago), 2021-09-07 23:01:49 -0700
    • Engine revision f0826da7ef
    • Dart version 2.14.0

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.2)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\my_user\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.2
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.10+0-b96-7249189)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[√] Android Studio (version 2020.3)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.10+0-b96-7249189)

[√] VS Code (version 1.60.0)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\my_user\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension can be installed from:
       https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Dart-Code.flutter

[√] Connected device (3 available)
    • Android SDK built for x86 (mobile) • emulator-5554 • android-x86    • Android 11 (API 30) (emulator)
    • Chrome (web)                       • chrome        • web-javascript • Google Chrome 93.0.4577.63
    • Edge (web)                         • edge          • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 93.0.961.38

• No issues found!
Process finished with exit code 0
```